# PHP for MS SQL 2005 version

Tags: php, sql-server

How can I run PHP in MS SQL Server 2005? 
From what I've known until now is that I need to get a php driver, but I am not sure if I need an apache or IIS, please enlighten me with this.

Is it possible for this scenario:

- MS SQL 2005 will be the main database,
- XAMPP will be the localhost,
- PHP will generate the queries from the MS SQL.

Or it is possible to run php in MS SQL itself without using any apache server?
Thanks

Comment: SQL Server is a database, PHP is an application (server-side) language. A database does not run an application. It runs and waits for the application to perform insert, select, update, delete operations on it.

Comment: Oh okay, so I really need xampp/wamp to run the php. Thanks for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer the question, yes.

If you want more than a TL;DR, more info:

There are basically a few different stack layers you need to think about:

1. **OS (Windows / Linux)**. Since you are talking IIS and MS SQL Server, I presume this choice has been made.
2. **Web Server**. The application listening on port 80/443/whatever else for HTTP requests. You can choose IIS, Apache, nginx etc.
3. **Application**. This is the logic of your application. You can choose PHP, Python, C# (.NET) or a multitude of programming languages. The application typically waits to be activated by the web server when requests come in.
4. **Database**. This is for storing data. You can choose MS SQL Server, MySQL, even any of the newer NoSQL solutions, or a combination of all. It is typically accessed by your application.

Each layer ought to be INDEPENDENT from one another (except IIS and MS SQL which only run on Windows). This means, in effect, you can choose:

- **L**inux, **A**pache, **P**HP, **M**ySQL ==> traditional **LAMP** stack.
- **W**indows, **I**IS, **C#**, **S**QL Server ==> **WISC** stack.

Most combinations work. It depends on which ones you are comfortable with.

XAMPP is essentially the same as LAMP, except with any OS - Windows/Linux. So if you want to use XAMPP, you have already inherently chosen MySQL (so why are you thinking about SQL Server). XAMPP is not your localhost. Perhaps only the web server (Apache/IIS) can claim to be localhost.

You're basically asking if tech stack of **W**indows, **A**pache, **P**HP, **S**QL Server (**WASP** stack) is possible, the answer is yes. What you need to do is download and set up Apache, PHP and SQL Server separately. There are tons of material online to help you with that. If you run into trouble, please go to ServerFault to post a question.

Comment: Hi, I've thoroughly read your comments and thanks for the inputs. 
I am using Windows XP and what I want to run using MS SQL is PHP.
Btw, if you are wondering why I want to use MS SQL Server 2005 rather than MySQL is because I am fetching data from a CallFlow(via eclipse) and the only database that will work on it is by using MS SQL 2005 or later versions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use wamp in order for you to meet your requirement.

MYSQL connected to your wamp .
Change your setting in wamp server to connect to your SQL server to store data.

Comment: Hi, where should I change the settings? Is it in the php .ini files? Thanks.
Btw, I am using XAMPP, I think it's almost the same as WAMP